# CORS with Embedded Jetty HTTPS

Tags: java, https, jetty

I want to allow CORS for Embedded Jetty HTTPS, but the following code is not working. I managed to make the code work for HTTP using the following code.

```
public class EmbeddingJettyWithServlet {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Setup Threadpool for multiple server connections
    QueuedThreadPool threadPool = new QueuedThreadPool();
    threadPool.setMaxThreads(500);

    //ThreadPool Server
    Server server = new Server(threadPool);

    // Configure jetty.home 
    String home = ".";

    // Configure ports for http
    ServerConnector http = new ServerConnector(server);
    http.setPort(9889);
    http.setIdleTimeout(30000);

    // Scheduler
    server.addBean(new ScheduledExecutorScheduler());

    //Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);

    // HTTPS Configuration
    HttpConfiguration https = new HttpConfiguration();
    https.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());

    SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(home + "/keystore.jks");
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("XXXXXXXXXX");
    sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("XXXXXXXXXXX");

    ServerConnector sslConnector = new ServerConnector(server,
            new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, "http/1.1"),
            new HttpConnectionFactory(https));
            sslConnector.setPort(9888);

    server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { http, sslConnector });

    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/kibitz");

    // Enable CORS - cross origin resource sharing (for http and https)
    FilterHolder cors = new FilterHolder();
    cors.setInitParameter("allowedOrigins", "*");
    cors.setInitParameter("allowedHeaders", "*");
    cors.setInitParameter("allowedMethods", "GET, POST");
    cors.setFilter(new CrossOriginFilter());
    context.addFilter(cors, "*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.INCLUDE));

    server.setHandler(context);

    server.start();
    server.join();
}
```

But I can't get the HTTPS on port 9888 to work. Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest *not* doing TLS/SSL in a Java web server, and move it to a reverse proxy (like Nginx) infront of your Java web server.  There's lots of good reasons to do this.. not limited to:  1. The proxy supports live reconfiguration  2. The proxy probably uses OpenSSL which gets regular TLS/SSL and cipher updates, where Java typically only does between major versions (especially with recent TLS/SSL vulnerabilities).  3. Management of JKS keystores and integration into an application is usually a painful process

Comment: I'm not too familiar with proxies. Does this also solve the CORS problem?

Comment: It changes your Java web server setup so that you only deal with HTTP in the Java code.  You delegate the TLS/SSL termination to a web server (proxy) infront of your Java web server.  In this case, if you have a working CORS setup for HTTP, and you put a HTTPS proxy setup infront of your Java web server, it should also work over HTTPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets start with using the `HttpConfiguration` properly.

```java
    // Setup Threadpool for multiple server connections
    QueuedThreadPool threadPool = new QueuedThreadPool();
    threadPool.setMaxThreads(500);

    //ThreadPool Server
    Server server = new Server(threadPool);
    int port = 9889;
    int portSecure = 9888;

    // Configure jetty.home 
    String home = ".";

    // HTTP Configuration
    HttpConfiguration http_config = new HttpConfiguration();
    http_config.setSecureScheme("https");
    http_config.setSecurePort(portSecure);

    // Configure Connector for http
    ServerConnector http = new ServerConnector(server,
            new HttpConnectionFactory(http_config));
    http.setPort(port);
    http.setIdleTimeout(30000);

    // HTTPS Configuration
    HttpConfiguration https_config = new HttpConfiguration(http_config);
    https_config.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());

    SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath(home + "/keystore.jks");
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("XXXXXXXXXX");
    sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("XXXXXXXXXXX");

    ServerConnector sslConnector = new ServerConnector(server,
            new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, "http/1.1"),
            new HttpConnectionFactory(https_config));
    sslConnector.setPort(portSecure);

    server.setConnectors(new Connector[] { http, sslConnector });
```

Your code had nothing defining what port was considered secure, and it also did not carry over the http configuration to the https side.

That should help in some regard.  However if you don't have your keystore created properly, then no amount of Jetty side configuration will help.

Comment: Ah, I see. After changing the code to yours above, I am still getting the same error: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:9888/. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS." I created the keystore using the command: keytool -genkey -alias sitename -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks -keysize 2048 with the same password as the password given in "sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword"

Comment: For CORS don't use localhost, use a real IP or hostname when testing.  Many browsers have special security for localhost.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! I've moved both my testing server and my webpage to a real IP address. The same error still occurs. The key I created within my keystore has the same password as the one I used for sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword. Any suggestions on what else might be going wrong? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

@Joakim Erdfelt was correct in that in my case, it was a keystore problem. After fumbling around with this, I discovered that the problem was my Firefox browser and untrusted certificates. Firefox, rather than giving the "Get Me Out of Here" message that it would give if you go to the https:// URL directly, the Javascript console, instead, gives the "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" error if your website is trying to access via a port.

In order to use https://, you must get a certificate from a trusted Certificate Authority and install it into your keystore. Some browsers will block the request if you generate your own certificate. This article's tremendously helpful in setting up your keystore correctly: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html.